# whatsapp business api not displaying public image urls in chat

Tags: whatsapp, gupshup

I'm testing whatsapp business api image section, it seems like the images available at platform are the ones which are getting displayed and no other images which I pick from s3 bucket or google images.

```
message = {"type": "image",
                               "previewUrl": "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0445/8545/1685/products/2_9082b428-a7fa-4648-84b5-b34cc1fea9a1_360x.png",
                               "originalUrl": "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0445/8545/1685/products/2_9082b428-a7fa-4648-84b5-b34cc1fea9a1_360x.png",
                               "caption": "some caption",
                               "filename": "Sample.jpeg"}
```

headers = {
'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
'apikey': 'mykey',
'cache-control': 'no-cache',
}

the above used url doesn't seem to be displayed in chat whereas https://www.buildquickbots.com/whatsapp/media/sample/png/sample01.png comes fine

Comment: You can checkout if Raven (https://ravenapp.dev) helps. You can send any notification (Sms, whatsapp, email etc) without integrating any provider APIs.

Comment: ok Proy, I'll check and revert back.

Comment: @Rishabh is your gupshup app in sandbox mode or it is live?